# Выбрать движок для 2D игры

Tags: android, разработка-игр

Доброго времени суток! Изучаю Java, уровень приблизительно средний, пишу приложения для Android средней сложности. Есть довольно большой опыт создания весьма сложных программ для Windows в конструкторе HiAsm. Знания других ЯП не имею. Очень хотел бы познакомиться с созданием игр на Android. Для начала в голову пришла идея создать простую игру по принципу "найди предмет на картинке", чтобы ознакомится с созданием 2D игр. Уважаемые специалисты, подскажите пожалуйста, на какой движок мне, как новичку в плане создания игр, стоит обратить внимание для создания данной 2D игры? Спасибо.

Comment: Думаю это можно сделать вообще без движка на базовом андроиде.

Comment: @pavel Согласен, но интересует именно движок. Через такую игру познакомиться с ним, возможно потом нечто другое реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам уже более года изучаю движок libGDX. Он кроссплатформенный, поддерживает и iOS. Игрушку дебажу на компьютере, не надо каждый раз переустанавливать на устройстве. Сам движок без физики, но можно подключить движок Box2D. 
Система 2D освещения также присутствует.
Советую к ознакомлению.

Comment: По Вашему опыту насколько сложен движок в освоении?